# Blackberry complex list

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

I've got an interesting problem that I'd like some advice and opinions on if you would be so kind. I'm not after code as I prefer to write that for myself. My background is J2ME and Android but I've recently taken up Blackberry.

What I need to write is something akin to the Android ListView albeit a little simpler.

Each row consists of 3 items. There's an image/icon, a multi-line (2 or 3 row) text element and an imagebutton of some form.

However, each row has only 2 columns. The icon/image & multi-line text are combined for the first column and are clickable (with both the column (0) plus the row ID identifiable). The next element in the row (1) is a clickable image (common to all rows - this also needs to have an identifiable row ID). There must be different actions for each column/row cell.

There is a need for multiple rows to be scrollable vertically and there may well be a lot of items.Each row needs to fit the screen width with the icon/multi-line text justified to the left and the clickable image justified to the right. Each row needs all of its components vertically justified (possibly centred) for neatness.

So what we have (for a row) is:

[clickable image/multi-line text combo][clickable image]

Ideally there will be a common background (gradient shaded) for each row once focussed. This should span both columns seamlessly.

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to have a [VerticalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/VerticalFieldManager.html) for the list, populated by [HorizontalFieldManagers](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/HorizontalFieldManager.html) for the row.

As for the inner part of the row (the columns) you can pass [FIELD_LEFT](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#FIELD_LEFT) to the first field and [FIELD_RIGHT](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#FIELD_RIGHT) for the second for alignment. The image-multitext field you can create yourself by extending [ButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html) and overriding the [paint](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html#paint%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics%29) method. You can use the [Graphics](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html) object to draw your [image](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#drawImage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20net.rim.device.api.system.EncodedImage,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and [text](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29). A different approach (and perhaps a simpler one) is to extend the HorizontalFieldManager, add your components and make it clickable by capturing the click events.

One thing to realize about Blackberry is that there are many ways to do something, if one thing doesn't work quite the way you want it to, try something different. Hope this help you get started!

Comment: That's why I asked the question. Thanks! I've tried a multitude of approaches today including the ones that you've suggested. I'm swamped with ideas and was wondering whether anyone has tried this. Thanks again for your suggestions. The key is that both images have to be vertically justified with the multi-text even though they're in different columns.

Comment: Glad I could help! I like your approach - asking for opinions and suggestions instead of asking people to write code for you :)

Comment: Just a quick addition to say I spent a few hours on this today and it works like a dream. There's actually quite a nice OO solution in all of this too. I used the first method. Cheers my friend :-)

Comment: Now here's another one to mull over. I have the above working perfectly. There's a UI issue here. There are 2 independent fields (in columns defined by a HFM). The normal BB selection thing works ... they're treated differently. The left is a bitmap and multi-line text - the right is another custom field that switches images if hovered over. When the image/text custom field is 'hovered' I can easily show it by colouring it ... HOWEVER (always one of those) ... the second column/custom field to the right doesn't highlight. Any thoughts on the best way of making it do this?

Comment: You wanna highlight them as a whole? Or do you mean it doesn't highlight when selected? Is this just a visual thing to have them highlighted as one field?